# What does lsboxd process do on os x?

Tags: macos, launchd, services, sandbox, launch-services

My firewall asked me for a connection from `lsboxd` (module com.apple.ls.boxd, ) to one another computer in my network to the port `tcp 548`. What does it do? I found that it is a part of sandbox technology of a OS X, but what is it more specifically? I found it in my `launchctl list` output:

```
com.apple.LaunchServices.lsboxd
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lsboxd` is part of the OS X Sandbox.

It allows communication between sandboxed applications.

`lsboxd` is in the Launch Services API. It is the Launch Services Sandbox Daemon, which governs what apps can launch apps in the OS X sandbox. You can peruse the App Sandbox Guide for more information about sandboxing.

PDF: [App Sandbox Design
Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxDesignGuide.pdf)

Comment: yep, but what does the lsbox do? (I already noticed, that it is a part of sandbox, but it is too general)

Comment: Sorry, I realized now that you noted that. It allows communication between sandboxed applications. (I have a document on it, but I can't seem to locate it at the moment.)

Comment: great! it would be nice if you could provide a link on that (maybe it is possible to find it for the name?)

Comment: lsboxd is in the Launch Services API. It is the Launch Services Sandbox Daemon, which governs what apps can launch apps in the OS X sandbox. You can peruse the App Sandbox Guide for more information about sandboxing.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxDesignGuide.pdf

Comment: Then why is lsboxd invoked when I double click an ics-file to import an event into the Calendar? No interprocess communication going on then, is it?

Answer (score 3):

Go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Calendars and uncheck the box next to the lsboxd

Why this part of XCode needs access to your Calendar, is a different story.

Answer (score -2):

Isboxd behaves as spyware, because it is spyware. The fact that it is part of OS X does not "explain" or justify its spyware function. It snoops for more PERSONAL info about you, the MAC user - nothing new, I hope...

Comment: Could you cite why this is spyware? What information is "snooped" and to where it is sent?